# Vaadin Charts Export to SVG after Zoom

Tags: svg, vaadin, vaadin-charts

Export of charts to PDF or SVG working.
Export of a zoomed chart results in SVG-File with chart without zoom.  Is there a way to generate a SVG image of the chart with the selected zoom?

Comment: The method I use to generate the SVG file is: SVGGenerator.getInstance().generate(chartWindow.getChart().getConfiguration(), width, height);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to export the zoomed chart by setting the extremes of the axes. I think axis extremes are not synchronized, but you can get the values from a ChartSelectionEvent for instance.

Comment: One more question: It seems that ChartSelectionEvent listener overrides the default behaviuor of the chart (zoomin-zoomout animantion and "reset zoom" button visualization): there is a way to avoid this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to not prevent default at the moment, you can emulate the zoom by setting the axis extremes, and with a Vaadin Button that calls `Configuration#resetZoom()`

Comment: If you think it would be useful to have support for an event with new selection that doesn't prevent the zooming you can create an issue in https://github.com/vaadin/charts/issues/new